# C++ GTest/GMock for class templates: Real method called instead of specified mock implementation

Tags: c++, templates, googletest, googlemock

Here is a simplified example (from gMock Cookbook) of a class template that I want to mock:

```
class StackInterface {
 public:
  virtual ~StackInterface();
  virtual int GetSize() const {
    return 3;
  }

};

template<typename Elem>
class MockStack : public StackInterface<Elem> {
 public:
  MockStack() : StackInterface<Elem>(){};

  MOCK_METHOD(int, GetSize, (), (const, override));

};
```

I'm using it as follows:

```
class StackTest : public testing::Test {
 public:
  StackTest() {
    mockStack_ = std::make_shared<MockStack<int>>();
  }

 protected:
  std::shared_ptr<MockStack<int>> mockStack_;

};

TEST_F(StackTest, TestGetSize1) {
  EXPECT_CALL(*mockStack_, GetSize()).WillRepeatedly(testing::Invoke([&]() -> int { return 5; }));

  StackInterface<int> myStack;
  auto res = myStack.GetSize();
  EXPECT_EQ(res, 5);
}
```

This test fails because returned value is 3 which is my real function - Why is my mock implementation being ignored? How can I ensure the mock implementation is used?

Comment: I haven't used gmock, but you're explicitly instantiating a `StackInterface<int>`.  Why would the mock be used at all?  I'd expect the optimizer to fully de-vritualize the call to `GetSize`.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetSize` method needs to be called by the mock object. That's `mockStack_`

```
template <typename Elem>
class StackInterface {
 public:
  StackInterface() {}
  virtual ~StackInterface() {}
  virtual int GetSize() const {
    return 3;
  }

};

template <typename Elem>
class MockStack : public StackInterface<Elem> {
 public:
  MockStack() : StackInterface<Elem>() {
        ON_CALL(*this, GetSize()).WillByDefault(Return(1)); }
  ~MockStack() {}
  MOCK_METHOD(int, GetSize, (), (const, override));
};

class StackTest : public testing::Test {
 public:
  StackTest() {
    mockStack_ = std::make_shared<MockStack<int>>();
  }
 protected:
  std::shared_ptr<MockStack<int>> mockStack_;

};

TEST_F(StackTest, TestGetSize1) {
  EXPECT_CALL(*mockStack_, GetSize()).WillRepeatedly(testing::Invoke([&]() -> int { return 5; }));

  EXPECT_EQ(mockStack_->GetSize(), 5);
}
```